# How can I terminate a running computation in Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate

I want to make a simple cdf file  that makes some hard computations inside Manipulate. Is there a simple way, lets say using a "stop!" Button,  to terminate the time consuming calculations--without  closing the web browser or Mathematica? 
To clarify my self:  The following code works well because 2014 is not large enough,  so Mathematica can  easily compute the sum of Logs.

`Manipulate[tick;
 tot = 1. Total[Log@Range[2014]];
 color = Green;, 
 tot, Button["Run", color = Red; tick = Not[tick], 
  Background -> Dynamic@color], {{color, Green}, None}, {{tot, 0}, 
  None}, {{tick, False}, None}, TrackedSymbols :> {tick}]`

but when I introduce range at the place of 2014 as in :

```
Manipulate[tick;
 tot = 1. Total[Log@Range[range]];
 color = Green;
 tot, Button["Run", color = Red; tick = Not[tick], 
  Background -> Dynamic@color], {{color, Green}, None}, {{tot, 0}, 
  None}, {{tick, False}, None}, {{range, 1}, 1, 300000000, 1}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {tick}]
```

the things  are coming very bad for huge values of range! 
So my question is :
Is it possible to terminate a running calculation from inside Manipulate?

Comment: whyare you multiplying by one here `1. Total[Log@Range[range]]` what does `1` do ?

Comment: @Nasser `1` nothing but `1.` works like `N`.

Comment: @Kuba I see. I wonder if this supposed to be faster/better than using N@ ?

Comment: @kornaros maybe it will be ok to use `MemoryConstrained` or something similar. Take a look at `See Also` part of the documentation for this.

Answer (score 3):

A good old fashioned way of doing it. Set a flag using another button, and check for the flag while doing the computation. (btw, I tried calling Abort[] and Interrupt[] when the second button is hit, but for some reason that did not stop the computation running in Manipulate. That is why I used this method below, which always works)

```
Manipulate[tick;

 Module[{r, i = 1},
  r = Range[range];
  tot = Total@N@Flatten@Rest@Reap[While[ok && i <= Length[r], Sow[Log[r[[i++]]]]]];
  color = Green;
  tot
  ],

 Row[{Button["Run", color = Red; ok = True; tick = Not[tick], 
   Background -> Dynamic@color, ImageSize -> {80, 40}],
   Button["Stop", ok = False; tick = Not[tick], ImageSize -> {80, 40}]
   }],
 {{range, 1, "range"}, 1, 3000000, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small},

 {{color, Green}, None},
 {{tot, 0}, None},
 {{tick, False}, None},
 {{ok, True}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {tick}

 ]
```

[image]

And if you want to see where the computation is at any time, you can use a counter (this is for illustration only. In real application, you might want to go easy on this as it will take time from the actual computation

```
Manipulate[tick;

 Module[{r},
  r = Range[range];
  tot = Total@N@Flatten@Rest@Reap[While[ok && i < Length[r], Sow[Log[r[[++i]]]]]];
  color = Green;
  tot
  ],

 Grid[{
   {Dynamic@Row[{"busy at item ", i}], SpanFromLeft},
   {Button["Run", color = Red; ok = True; i = 0; tick = Not[tick], 
    Background -> Dynamic@color, ImageSize -> {80, 40}],
    Button["Stop", ok = False; tick = Not[tick], ImageSize -> {80, 40}]
    }}, Spacings -> {1, 1}],

 {{range, 1, "range"}, 1, 30000000, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small},

 {{color, Green}, None},
 {{tot, 0}, None},
 {{tick, False}, None},
 {{ok, True}, None},
 {{i, 0}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {tick}     
 ]
```

[image]